# "Express Edition" Tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

Do we have any tags for the "express editions" of computer programs? Usually, these are toned-down versions of the program which are free or less money. Obviously, this means there can usually only be an "express" edition of a program which is paid for.

Is there a tag for this on StackOverflow or any other computer-related StackExchange site?

Comment: That would be a good idea. Often the solution to a problem could be buying the full version.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think of it that way. I meant there can be general problems with the Express Edition not present in the Full Edition, as well as the other way around. Strange, but true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we do have them where practical. Check this example for SQL Server 2008 Express:

[image]

The rules for this are much the same as those for minor versions - they should only exist where there is a consequential point of difference.

Comment: So we don't have a general "Express Edition" tag? We just have tags for each of the express editions of certain programs?

Comment: A general "express edition" tag would be a dictionary definition meta tag: it means something different to everyone, nobody could have a meaningful subscription to it in the real world, and especially the newest metric... nobody can be an "expert" in "express edition."